# Best way to update Tomcat 7 of Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, tomcat7

Ubuntu Server 12.04 repository has Tomcat 7 in version 7.0.26. I prefer using this installation because it creates the user, init script and log rotation configuration.

What would you suggest to keep it updated with the latest version: download from tomcat.apache.org, copy the jars and diff the configuration files or use the Debian repository?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by the "latest version". If you *really* want the most recent version you are going to have to use tarballs.

If it's a production system I'd use the packages so they are automatically managed for dependencies etc unless you know you need newer functionality.

Comment: I mean the newest version. Currently it's 7.0.42. The Debian repository has it, do you think it's safe to use it with Ubuntu?

Comment: It should be but you are taking a risk adding non-Ubuntu repositories since you could get package conflicts. But if you are just running Tomcat and 7.0.35 is not new enough then you should be OK. For the default Ubuntu build run "sudo apt-get install tomcat7"